# Should/could I cache my data (from db) to reduce response time for my webpage?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm building a website that contains a search page. There a several dropdowns each with multiple values to choose from and I don't feel like having all these search parameters hardcoded. All the search parameters are saved in my db, but I don't want to make a call to my db every time the search page needs to be rendered.  Is there a way I can cache my data from db, so I don't need to go all the way down in the db every time?

Comment: Which technology are you using ? ASP.NET ? PHP ?

Comment: .. Forgot to mention that :p ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server side you can, if your user is logged, use session : http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

For client side you can use local storage : http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html